# Using jQuery to return json values to a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I've created a jsfiddle with my code - not the CSS section has the PHP logic just for demonstration.

I want to enter a postcode in the zip field - then once the button is clicked it queries the geocode googlemaps script and returns a json object - I am just having problems returning this object back to the form fields. I can see the json in the console log - but i'm doing something wrong when passing it back to the view. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/JxBQZ/2/

Here is the js file

```
    $('form').on('click','#geocode',function(event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    var zip = $('#geocode_field').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/test/gmaps",
        data: { zip: zip},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.street);
        }   
    });
});


<form>
<label>Zip</label>
<input type="text" id="geocode_field" name="zip" /><button id="geocode">Search</button>
<label>Street 1</label>
<input type="text" id="street1" name="street1" />
<label>Street 2</label>
<input type="text" id="street2" name="street2" />
<label>Town</label>
<input type="text" id="town" name="town" /> 
<label>County</label>
<input type="text" id="county" name="county" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a `dataType` to `json` instead of `jsonp`, because you called to your own domain. jsonp is used for cross domain ajax and it also required difference returned format.

```
dataType: "json",
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have changed it to json from jsonp as recommended - still unable to use the pass the variable - in the Chrome debugger I can see the following in the Network tab
{"street":"27th Avenue","town":"Astoria","county":"Queens"} - not sure why i cannot use data.street to pass the values into a form field..

Comment: did you received data from server as json ? I mean when you console.log(data.street) is it displayed anything ?

Comment: yeh - i've not long been up and think my brain was still sleeping - thanks for your help on the dataType otherwise i'd have been on that for awhile :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$.ajax()` method, use `$.post()` method. It will then update your views part.

Try something like this:

```
$.post("/test/gmaps", { data: zip}, function(data) {
for (var key in data) {
    $('#fetchdata').html(data.street); 
   }}, "json");
```

here, `#fetchdata` is the id in which data is to be received, it can be span, input box etc. In your query when you return the value, return it in json_encoded format. Such as:

```
function some(){
//your query
$data_to_return[] = something;
echo json_encode($data_to_return);
}
```

You can read more about the `$.post()` method **[HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it... its too early. :(

```
    $('form').on('click','#geocode',function(event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    var zip = $('#geocode_field').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/test/gmaps",
        data: { zip: zip},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.street);
            $('#street1').val(data.street);
        }   
    });
});
```